# Anyway to set taskbar height in registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar

I have a issue that my taskbar does not want to stay 3 high.

It is not a windows issue more so the screen that I am using disconnects itself when I turn it OFF and when I turn it ON windows detects it as a new device.

So I am wondering if someplace in regedit there is a key that I can set to keep it at 3 high so that it does not reset to the default 1 high.

I am currently running **Windows 10 Pro 64bit**

[image: http://cloud.dloaded.com/i/5673777a8ee1d.png]